# Generate buttons in Tkinter with a different name each time

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to generate a button for each .py document in a file, and each button give a different argument to the function

```
for name in files:
    if name[-3:]=='.py':
        a=name[:-3]
        button=Button(barre, text=a, command=python_file(a))
        button.pack()

def python_file(name):
    text = Text(barre)
    text.insert(name)
    os.popen("python3 "+a+".py","r")
```

It basicly write the name of the python file and execute. But, I need to give a different name to each button, just like : **button1, button2 (...)**.

Also when I run my code, It execute the function each time thee is a new python file.
Thx for helping !!

Comment: save the buttons in a list or dictionary instead of giving them unique variable names. There are many questions on this site related to creating buttons in a loop. As for the other problem, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/5767228/7432

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the command argument in your button to:

```
button=Button(barre, text=a, command=lambda a=a: python_file(a))
```

The argument passing to your function is the one which is the last value in the for loop. To pass the current value, you need to specify it through the lambda function.

Also, change the os.popen method like this to fully execute the code inside the file.

```
c = os.popen("python3 "+a+".py","r")
print(c.read())
```